# makefile for openGL cannot find -lSOIL

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile, glsl

I have only a couple hours experience with GLSL (OpenGL Shading Language) and I`ve found a sample code, when I tried to run it by using its makefile I got the following error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lSOIL
/tmp/ccBamtAW.o:glinit.cpp:function initTextures(): error: undefined reference to 'SOIL_load_image'
/tmp/ccBamtAW.o:glinit.cpp:function initTextures(): error: undefined reference to 'SOIL_load_image'
/tmp/ccBamtAW.o:glinit.cpp:function initTextures(): error: undefined reference to 'SOIL_load_OGL_single_cubemap'
/tmp/ccBamtAW.o:glinit.cpp:function initTextures(): error: undefined reference to 'result_string_pointer'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

And here is my makefile :

```
LIB=-Llib
INC=-Iinc
SRC=sample.cpp glinit.cpp glentry.cpp utils.cpp 
DIRS=lib/ inc/ res/

all:
    g++ $(SRC) $(LIB) $(INC) -o sample -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lSOIL -lpthread

dist:
    @tar -czvf sample.tar.gz $(DIRS) $(SRC) Makefile --exclude "*~"
```

Is there anyone who can tell me what is wrong with this makefile ?

Comment: You *have* installed the [Simple OpenGL Image Library](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg actually I`ve installed only opengl and glut stuff. Not explicitly install something like wrote, I`ll do it immediately, thanks